# Find and update with pessimistic_write lock could not prevent from optimistic lock failure?

Tags: spring-data, optimistic-locking, pessimistic-locking

I've tried to find and update one record using pessimistic_write lock, like below,

```
transactionService.executeTransaction(() -> {
    Entity newEntity = em.find(entityClass, id, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
    newEntity = setEntityWithProperty.setEntity(newEntity, property);
});
```

I'm using the transactionTemplate in Spring.The entity itself has one version field to use the optimistic lock. With pessimistic_write lock, during the transaction (find and then update), other threads are supposed not able to read or write the record, right? But when commit the transaction, I can still get OptimisticLockFailuerException. Why this happens?

Comment: due to the few facts known, I would suppose that `OptmisticLockException` *must* come from another entity...